# Power Query Demote headers in combine

Tags: powerquery

Im trying to combine 50 .xlsm files. Each file has vital information in the 1st row. Power Query automatically assumes that the first row of the first .xlsm file contains Headers. Therefore it automatically promotes headers from the first file and ignores the first row of the following 49 .xlsm files.

How do i stop power query from assuming that the first row contains headers?

Answer (score 0):

Could you share your code? I'm asking because from the documentation if you use **Table.Combine**
it should merge all tables, merging all headers too.

You can check this in the second example

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-combine#example-2

Which means that probably you use a different method.